# Android File encryption

Tags: android, encryption

Hi I was wondering if anybody would know the best way to encrypt a file before I send it to the server and then how to unencrypt it once on the server? Files could be txt or jpg...I dont know much about encryption..thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can check the developer documentation for Cipher [here](http://developer.android.com/reference/javax/crypto/Cipher.html). That list should be sufficient for your needs. Also, check this question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4956274/whats-wrong-with-this-encryption-code-in-android) for guidance on how to use the API.

Comment: Do you know how i could use this to encrypt a whole file?

Comment: I used this to encrypt and image...however when i decrypt it it is corrupt? does this mean i can not encrypt my images?

Comment: @Usmaan: No, getting a corrupt image means something went wrong. Why don't you edit your question and place the code you have written there in addition to the existing question. It would help debug.

Comment: @Usmaan: Were you able to complete it? Where did the error lie?

Answer (score 0):

It depends on the purpose of your encryption.

If you just want it to be sent securely, i.e. you want to secure the communication of the data, then just use an HTTPS API connection.

If you write your own encryption code in the app to encrypt on the device itself, someone can reverse-engineer the app, and use your code to write a decrypter, so it's never going to be very secure.

Comment: hmmm i have imported import javax.net.ssl.HttpsURLConnection; and tried to implement this but for some reason my files are not being sent to the server, or not being received should i say ?

Comment: I don't have a certificate i believe

Comment: For HTTPS connections, you need to ensure that there is a secure certificate installed on the web server. You can buy them for about $100, and you can also create test certificates on web servers (how will depend on what web server you are using). For a production environment, you will definitely need to buy a certificate.

Answer (score 0):

If your looking for an easy to use encryption program to protect your files try Sensiguard www.sensiguard.com Rated as the easiest to use product, you can encrypt your personal files easily and safely. fully integrated into windows explorer. Use the USB Vault software that comes with sensiguard to encrypt files that you can decrypt at location. (note for the vault you might need the microsoft c++ redistributables 2010

Comment: Hmmmm is there something similar which is free

Comment: ideally i just want to put the sd card into machine and encrypt it so if it is stolen nobody can get into it. However i still want applications to be able to save things to it on the android phone.